# Nombre de la etiqueta doblemente escapado como HTML

Tags: bug, estado-completado

Al tratar de ver las revisiones de una etiqueta que contiene tildes, por ejemplo

```
http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/2784/revisions
```

Se puede ver que el nombre de la etiqueta esta incorrectamente doblemente escapado como HTML

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Viendo el código fuente se puede ver claramente el problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you; yes, we are double-encoding that. This has been fixed and will be available after the next deploy. This is usually every few hours. This only affects tag wiki articles.

(via google translate)

Gracias; sí, estamos codificándolo doblemente. Esto se ha solucionado y estará disponible después del próximo despliegue. Esto ocurre por lo general cada pocas horas. Esto sólo afecta a los artículos de etiquetas wiki.

Comment: Thanks Marc nice to read a response from you!

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz actually, it looks like the `<title>` is still wrong; fixing that